# I want to install an older godot engine

Tags: installation, windows-7, 32-bit, godot, launching

I tried installing the latest (3.2 stable release). And the download went fine. But when I launched it, the engine always not respond at first. It'll work tho when I wait for a few seconds or a minute. It does the same thing when I am trying to launch my project (which is empty).

I started thinking that maybe my GPU isn't compatible with the release so I thought I wanna install the earlier versions, like 2.1. So I did. It launched without error --if without error means that my godot "dashboard" will not properly "launch". Just take a look at my photo.

Also, I don't actually know what GPU is. I just did what the google told me to do: run "dxdia" on the run. And on the display it said "Intel(R) Graphic Media chuchuchu" and I assumed it is my so-called "Graphics thing".

Can you help me with intalling the older Godot versions? Coz I don't think it installed properly.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpTai.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can download old versions of Godot Engine here:
https://downloads.tuxfamily.org/godotengine/

You can try to run Godot in verbose mode to see what is the problem. Open cmd, go to the folder where is Godot installed and execute Godot with `--verbose` param to see what is happening:

```
cd <folder_for_godot>
godot.exe --verbose
```